# Tanstack Query - Update dependant query from an other component

Tags: tanstack

I have two remote components in my application.
I would like to create a query that is deactivated by default and used by one component.
I would like my second component to activate the previous query.
The only way I've found is to use a store to share the data between the two components.
Is there a simpler solution ?